# RC step-response and how to go about voltage across capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, step-response

I have this task with this circuit:

[image]

and the question is:

[image]

First I looked what would happen when t = 0:

To begin with, Vc(0) = 0 V, the reason for that is that t = 0 and before that the switch has been open a very long time which leads to the fact that the capacitor have not had the chance to charge and that is why the capacitor is 0 V.

So that gave me:

Vc(t) = Vc(∞) + [Vc(0) - Vc(∞)]e^(-t/τ)

And then I looked what would happen when t = ∞:

If I let the circuit run for a long time that implies that the capacitor will act like an open circuit. That leads to that the voltage over terminal a and b will be the voltage across the capacitor.

Vc(∞) = Vab

Which gave me this circiut:

**Edit: I wrongly put 6 A on VA, but of course it should be 6 V.**

[image]

Now to my question:

I want to calculate the Vab and my main question is if I could use the voltage divider rule and calculate it as:

10000(R2)/(10000(R2)+5000(R3)) * 6 V = 4 V

or do I have to consider the R1 too? Should I think another way around?

Comment: R1 needs to be considered too.  The simplest way to analyze this is to replace R1 and R2 with the Thevenin equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going about this in a complicated manner when, in fact you can convert the [three resistors into one resistor](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/thevenin.html) and, the voltage source becomes 3 volts. So, the 6 volt voltage source, R1 and R2 form a potential divider that has an open circuit voltage of 3 volts.

[image]

Looking into that circuit you should be able to see that the equivalent resistance is just R1||R2 or 5000 ohms.

So now you have a new circuit that is a 3 volt source in series with 5000 ohms connected to R3 in series with C. You can simplify further to put R3 (also 5000 ohms) in series with the previously calculated 5000 ohms from the parallel connection of R1 and R2.

The final circuit you end up with is 3 volts feeding C via 10 kohms.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Okay, I got it that I can get out both the equivalent resistance and the voltage. So basically, am I thinking right that I can find τ = RC and in the end plug what I have in v(t) = V0e^(-t/ τ)?

Comment: No, that's not the right formula - [see this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capchg.html) i.e. v(t) = \$3(1 - e^{-t/\tau})\$

Comment: Thank you, I got it! :)